# Align multiline text in Radio group android

Tags: android, radio-button

I am working on a quiz application, in this application i have to show 4 radio buttons with some multi-line text just like in snapshot. For this i have used radio-group, but the problem is that radio buttons are not aligned with the text properly as shown in snapshot. It becomes hosh-pash. Please somebody provide some suggestions. Thanks in advance[image]

here is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/txtQ"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/screen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textQno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textRem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textQuis"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="144dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbQ1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbQ2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbQ3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbQ4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bMainPre"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                    android:text="@string/bPrev" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bMainNext"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                    android:text="@string/bNext" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bshowAnswer"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                    android:text="@string/bShow" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bSubAns"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                    android:text="@string/bsumit" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to add aligned text to a radiobutton:

```
<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbQ1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="YOUR TEXT HERE" 
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:layout_gravity="center"    
                android:layout_margin="5dip" />
```

Comment: there is  no way to do it with radio group??

Comment: See my edit. You can add text to a radiobutton because it is an extension of a textview.

Comment: i know it. Actually text is coming from server and i am setting it dynamically to radio button through setText() method